# How do I get the list of open file handles by process in vb6

Tags: vb6, process

How do I get the list of open file handles by process id in vb6?

I'm interested in digging down and getting the file names as well.

Looking for the programmatic equivalent of what process explorer does.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Please do not keep asking questions when you do not get an answer. Supply the information requested instead. These two questions should not have been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240742/view-opened-locked-files-in-my-system
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226718/how-to-get-the-filename-of-the-process-that-is-currently-runing-in-vb6

Answer (score 0):

Use [***Handle.exe***](http://download.sysinternals.com/files/Handle.zip) from [***Sysinternals***](http://www.sysinternals.com).

```
Shell ("c:\...\handle.exe ... >> " & app.path & "\tmp.txt",vbHide)
   '...Write something which will get contents from App.path & "\tmp.txt" ...
   '...Wait some time ,because killing the file at this moment 
   'will bring an error
Kill App.Path & "\tmp.txt"
```

Comment: The `Shell` function doesn't handle output redirection. You'll need to use `Cmd.exe` with the correct command line to do that.

Comment: Oh, and when giving code, please try and make sure it compiles first, ideally copying from the IDE rather than writing by hand.