# How to get the filename of the process that is currently runing in vb6

Tags: vba, vb6

Is there a way to find the currently open file from an Excel or Word process etc.? I want to get the list of all running processes in Windows and which files they currently have open.

Comment: Erm, your question part 1, part 2, and the title don't match...

Comment: I now see that this is the second of a set of three questions on the same topic. This is not now SO works. (1)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202842/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-open-file-handles-by-process-in-vb6  (3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240742/view-opened-locked-files-in-my-system

Answer (score 3):

How about a list of running processes using VBA

```
Function getProcessInfo()
''On Error Resume Next
Dim objProcess, process, strNameOfUser
ComputerName = "."
Set objProcess = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}\\" _
      & ComputerName & "\root\cimv2").ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")
For Each process In objProcess
    If process.Name <> "System Idle Process" And process.Name <> "System" Then
        ''Debug.Print process.Name
        Debug.Print process.Name & "," & process.executablepath _
            & "," & process.Priority & "," & process.sessionid _
            & "," & strNameOfUser & "," & process.handlecount _
            & "," & process.ThreadCount
    End If
Next

Set objProcess = Nothing
End Function
```

Modified from : http://www.windowsadminscripts.com/coding/networking/processes/

Perhaps a list of open windows might be more useful:

```
Private Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2
Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long

Sub ListWins(Optional Title = "*", Optional Class = "*")
    Dim hWndThis As Long
    hWndThis = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString)
    While hWndThis
        Dim sTitle As String, sClass As String
        sTitle = Space$(255)
        sTitle = Left$(sTitle, GetWindowText(hWndThis, sTitle, Len(sTitle)))
        sClass = Space$(255)
        sClass = Left$(sClass, GetClassName(hWndThis, sClass, Len(sClass)))
        If sTitle Like Title And sClass Like Class Then
            Debug.Print sTitle, sClass
        End If
        hWndThis = GetWindow(hWndThis, GW_HWNDNEXT)
    Wend
End Sub
```

Use it like so:

```
ListWins "*.doc*"
```

This will list all Word windows with a title containing *.doc*

Comment: remou thank u very much for your code this code is show what process in runing with application for example wmplayer.exe proccess show the resulte c:\programfile\windows media player etc but not shown what file is runing in windows media player .. i need current runing file not current runing program

Comment: You might like to read http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ITCG/thread/0c6a8b1b-c99e-402c-bf9b-a09343aaa724

Comment: remou nothing this post.. handle.exe is good tool but its working on command prompt

Comment: I have added some more notes.

Comment: thank u very much remou once again your code is working but still little bit problem your last code show the title of current file it *.doc working but if i use this code windows media player to detect current  runing video file it shows nothing please check this link i want to add same functionality in vb6 http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason, why you use vb6?

Edit:
I don't know, if that will help you, but here is a link, with some examples how to get a process list in VB6: http://wiki.robotz.com/index.php/Process_List_and_Locate_VB6

Comment: bcz i already done this in vb.net but every time when i install windows i need to installed .net framework if i done this in vb6...no need to installed anything

Comment: Hwo do you do it in .NET? The same concepts/Win32 APIs will work in other languages too. Also, do you need your own app? [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) does it already.

Comment: i need same funcationality like handle.exe in vb6

Comment: for example a windows media player runing in proccess a track avseq1.dat is runing i want to get runing track name in my vb6 application

Comment: That will require custom support for every application to get "current documents" rather than jsut every file they have open (Some will open and close the file itself)