# How to get the currently running application using vb6

Tags: vb6

I'm currently working on a simple key-logger application using VB 6, and I need to get the application names that when the key's are logged. I tried several things that was in some threads but it didn't help.

Comment: "i tried several things" what are those?

Comment: Provide what you have done so far, then you can get more helps.

Comment: If you are using VB6 then why all the other tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the window title for current application. Based on window title and window handle, you can get sufficient details.

Code is in vb.net

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetForegroundWindow() As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowText(hWnd As IntPtr, text As StringBuilder, count As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Private Function GetCurrentWindowTitle() As String
    Const  nChr As Integer = 256
    Dim str As New StringBuilder(nChr)
    Dim handle As IntPtr = GetForegroundWindow()

    If GetWindowText(handle, str, nChr) > 0 Then
        Return str.ToString()
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast your eye over this one, it is a VB6 post which could point you in the right direction [filenames of the process that is currently running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226718/how-to-get-the-filename-of-the-process-that-is-currently-runing-in-vb6)

If that one doesn't help then try this one [VB6 listing running processes](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=61)