# Check if Excel is open from Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am struggling to figure out if I should close Excel after doing several operation to it. If I already have Excel open (A.xls, D.xls) and start my Word macro which takes value from active document and dumps it into B.xls, I want my macro to close B.xls but leave A and C open. However if I *don't* have A and C open, I want my macro to close Excel completely after it's finished running.

I tried several ways to achieve this with out succeeding:

```
 Dim oXLApp As Object
    ' Get excel object
    closeExcelMy = FileHandling.setExcelObject(oXLApp)

'*********************************************************
'********* define if we need to close excel after sub is done
'***********************************************************
Function setExcelObject(ByRef oXLApp As Object) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo notOpen
    setExcelObject = False
    Set oXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
'    On Error GoTo 0

'    If oXLApp Is Nothing Then
'        Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'        setExcelObject = True
'    End If

notOpen:
    Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    setExcelObject = True
    '~~> Hide Excel
    'oXLApp.Visible = True

'    If oXLApp.Workbooks.Count < 1 Then
'       setExcelObject = True
'    End If
End Function
```

I want my function to return `true` if I can close Excel otherwise `false`.

How can I achieve this from VBA in Word?

Answer (score 1):

This will check if workbooks `A.xls` and `C.xls` are both open.

If either of the workbooks are not open, it will close the entire Excel application. You should be able to work this into your code and get a working solution.

```
Option Explicit
Function areWorkbooksOpen() As Boolean

    Dim wbA As Workbook, wbC As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next ' Turn off error handling
    Set wbA = Workbooks("A.xls")
    Set wbC = Workbooks("C.xls")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wbA Is Nothing Or wbC Is Nothing Then
        areWorkbooksOpen = False
    Else
        areWorkbooksOpen = True
    End If
End Function

Sub mainCode()

    ' Your code


    If Not areWorkbooksOpen Then
        Excel.Application.Quit  ' Close entire session of excel
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

If you haven't already found the excel application, then you will need to do that. The below takes finding the excel application into consideration.

> You will also need to enable 'Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library' within References

```
Option Explicit
Function areWorkbooksOpen() As Boolean
    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application, wb As Workbook
    Dim wbA As Workbook, wbC As Workbook

    Set excelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    For Each wb In excelApp.Workbooks
        If wb.Name = "A.xls" Then
            Set wbA = wb
        ElseIf wb.Name = "C.xls" Then
            Set wbC = wb
        End If
    Next wb

    If wbA Is Nothing Or wbC Is Nothing Then
        areWorkbooksOpen = False
    Else
        areWorkbooksOpen = True
    End If

    Set excelApp = Nothing
End Function

Sub mainCode()

    ' Your code

    If Not areWorkbooksOpen Then
        Excel.Application.Quit
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that I do not know the names A and C(The users has random number of workbooks open), maybe I could loop through collection of workboooks somehow? I use 'Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")' to avoid setting the references to object library. This is due to the reason that i spread the macro in normal.dotm and that if the version change to 15 it will fail or?

Comment: The second code I posted loops through the workbooks within the excel applications collection. But if you don't know the names of workbooks A and C, I'm not sure there's anything you can do...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, maybe not elegant but it works. I simply check window names to see if it's called something like Excel, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226718/how-to-get-the-filename-of-the-process-that-is-currently-runing-in-vb6).

```
Option Explicit

Private Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2
Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long

Sub test()
Dim closeExcel As Boolean
closeExcel = ListWins("*Excel*")
End Sub
Function ListWins(Optional Title = "*", Optional Class = "*") As Boolean
    Dim hWndThis As Long
    ListWins = True
    hWndThis = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString)
    While hWndThis
        Dim sTitle As String, sClass As String
        sTitle = Space$(255)
        sTitle = Left$(sTitle, GetWindowText(hWndThis, sTitle, Len(sTitle)))
        sClass = Space$(255)
        sClass = Left$(sClass, GetClassName(hWndThis, sClass, Len(sClass)))
        If sTitle Like Title And sClass Like Class Then
            ListWins = False
            Debug.Print sTitle, sClass
        End If
        hWndThis = GetWindow(hWndThis, GW_HWNDNEXT)
    Wend
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It should not close the other Excel files.

I used the following:

```
Sub SomeMacro()

Dim ExcelProgram As Object
Dim ExcelFile As Object
Dim EventData As Object

'Here you would be using your script to develop/determine the file path
ExcelFilePath = "C:\   Some File Path.xls"

'Starting Excel
Set ExcelProgram = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'Not allowing it to be visible
ExcelProgram.Application.Visible = False

'Opening the desired Excel File
Set ExcelFile = ExcelProgram.Application.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)

'Here you would execute some script for the Excel Sheet


Somecode here



'Quiting the Excel Application
ExcelProgram.Quit

'clean up Objects for next use
Set ExcelProgram = Nothing
Set ExcelFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

and it does not close any other Excel Document that is open, because you closing the created `ExcelProgram.Quit` and not `Excel.Application.Quit`

Comment: Thanks, however if you want to do things with an excel workbook that is already open, you will need to set reference to that that book instead of open it. In my case either the workbook is open by the user(setting reference to the workbook by name), if that fails then i check if its open  by some other user, (i just try to read it binary to figure out if this is the case) if that's work, then i check if the user has excel open, then i open the workbook. I guess i can modified the code to use your method, I will look into when i get the time. Thanks:)

Comment: Always hard to understand the context of questions posted and also the various senators which there can be. I'm well conversant with working with objects and scanning through active documents. So this was a good question for info