# View opened locked files in my system

Tags: file-io, vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the filename of the process that is currently runing in vb6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226718/how-to-get-the-filename-of-the-process-that-is-currently-runing-in-vb6)

i want to  displays the list of all opened files on my system. For each opened file, additional information is displayed: handle value, read/write/delete access, file position, the process that opened the file. here is a link http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html i need same functionality in vb6

Comment: It seems to me that you want the people on SO to provide you with commercially viable code. This is not what SO is for. You have got hints in this and your previous post. If you have code that you need help with, post it. If you want an existing application, [project explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) is available.

Comment: I see you had a question prior to that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202842/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-open-file-handles-by-process-in-vb6 **Three** duplicate questions is excessive, to say the least.

Comment: Why not just use Nirsoft's utility from the command line/shell? You can do that in VB6.

Comment: HK1 HOW CAN I USE Nirsoft's utility THIS IN VB6

Comment: Remou Thank u very much your yesterdate support but my problem still here  your code is working but still little bit problem your last code show the title of current file it *.doc working but if i use this code windows media player to detect current runing video file it shows nothing please check this link i want to add same functionality in vb6 nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be hard from vb6 to list all files.
Look at this, for example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18975/Listing-Used-Files

Comment: thanks alexey yes this code in c++ i need this in vb6

Comment: You can write dll or ActiveX component on C++ based on link and use it in vb6.