# Is there a way to tell what the file name is where VB6 has only assigned it a number?

Tags: file, vb6

I'm working with some old VB6 code and it's still new to me. I know that in VB6 you assign an integer to represent a file. I have a program that uses quite a few files and it's tough to tell what file it's working with when it will only display the number when I mouse over the variable. (pic below).

[image]

So in the example above, how do i know what file #5 is?

Thanks

Comment: The variable IS a number. mousing over isn't going to get you there. This answer gets you part of the way there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202842/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-open-file-handles-by-process-in-vb6

Comment: @JohnFx, the file "number" is not a Windows file handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to modify the program to 'register' filenames with their file numbers:

```
Dim FileRegister as Collection

Dim FileName as String
Dim FileNumber as Integer

...

FileRegister.add FileName, str(FileNumber)
Open FileName For Output as #FileNumber

...

FileRegister.Remove str(FileNumber)
Close #FileNumber
```

Comment: Make sure you only do it on success (or remove it on failure) otherwise you may well get duplicate files registered with the same file number (if you're using `FreeFile()`)

Comment: @Deanna I'm fairly sure that the Collection will not hold duplicates.  Its more likely that the `Remove` will have nothing to remove.

Comment: Exactly. That's why you should add it AFTER the file has been opened successfully, as you don't know it's valid until afterwards. If you add it, and the open fails, then VB may will give you the same file number later on, which will then fail as it'll be a duplicate entry.

Comment: Thanks, that helps quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

- Search the code for the variable name? Do you have [MZTools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx)? It's a free plugin with excellent search facilities.
- Trace the code execution back to see where the unit number comes from? Use the call stack view when debugging, or use [MZTools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx) to list all calls to any routine.
- (Last resort) add logging.

  - Every time a file is opened, log the filename and unit number.
  - Every time a file is closed, log the unit number.
  - You could leave the logging in the production code, maybe with a way to turn it on/off at runtime. It could be useful again.